# What's the difference between the two sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Bringing up children does not only mean providing them with food, clothes and toys but also giving them attention.

> Bringing up children means not only providing them with food,
> clothes and toys but also giving them attention.

They're from a chapter of a grammar book focusing on parallelism, I wonder if there's any difference between the two?

Answer (score 4):

When you write "not only X but also Y," X and Y must be grammatically parallel. If X is a noun phrase, Y should be a noun phrase. If X is a gerund, Y should be a gerund. And so on.

Here are your sentences with labels for convenience:

> 1. Bringing up children does not only mean providing them with food, clothes and toys but also giving them attention.
> 2. Bringing up children means not only providing them with food, clothes and toys but also giving them attention.

In #1, X is "mean" and Y is "giving." The first is a bare infinitive verb, while the second is a gerund. Or to make that even simpler, Y ends in "-ing" but X does not. They perform different grammatical roles.

Furthermore, the sense of "mean" seems to apply to X as well as Y. But the grammar does not permit this. It *follows* "not only" so it attaches only to X, which is clearly not the intent.

The opposite is true of #2. X is "providing" and Y is "giving." They are both gerunds. Or more simply, they both end in "-ing." You can also see that by placing "mean *before* "not only," it correctly applies to X as well as Y. We can interpret the idea as follows:

> Bringing up children means providing them with food, clothes and toys. Bringing up children also means giving them attention.

In short, #2 is the better sentence.